# How to run lakefs in goland?

Tags: lakefs

I downloaded the source code of version 0.68.0 and imported it into goland. I found some functions are missing. E.g. I can't find the definition of function "HandlerFromMuxWithBaseURL" which is invoked at line 94 in pkg/api/serve.go. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to run `make` or `make gen` first. Part of the code like the above handler is generated.
In a newer version of lakefs this handler code is part of the committed code.

Comment: This step is documented in the [Contributing to lakeFS](https://docs.lakefs.io/contributing.html) page